# translate validation messages using jqbootstrapvalidation with Symfony2

Tags: jquery, validation, symfony, jquery-plugins

I am using jqbootstrapvalidation plugin to validate my forms in the client side using jquery.

The application that I am currently developing using Symfony2 provide multiple languages and I use Symfony translation to assure this functionality and this is a simple example.

```
$builder->add ( 'lastName', 'text', array (
                'label' => 'register.last_name' 
        ) )
```

Now, I want to translate the validation messages in the jqbootstapvalidation plugin so I used the data-validation attribute as in this example:

```
->add ( 'firstName', 'text', array (
            'label' => 'register.first_name'
            'attr' => array (
                    'minlength' => "5",
                    'data-validation-minlength-message' => 'register.min_length'
            ) 
    ) )
```

However the output I get is this 'register.min_length' instead of the validation message in the messages file.

I hope you will be able to understand my problem and help me resolve it.

Comment: [tag:jquery-validate] is not `jqbootstrapvalidation`.  Please be more mindful when tagging your questions.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could register your [form as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services).

Afterwards inject the translator service  `@translator` into the constructor of your form.

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

protected $translator;

public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

Finally use the translator inside your form-type to translate the validation message.

```
array(
// ...
'data-validation-minlength-message' => $this->translator->trans('register.min_length'),
),
```

Make sure you call your form as a service or pass the translator to the form if you construct the object with `new YourFormType($this->container->get('translator'))`.

Comment: Thank you man you saved my day. It really works! However you have some syntaxe error.

Instead of:

$this->container->get('translator')

I used

$this->get('translator')

and instead of:

$this->translator->translate

I used

$this->translator->trans

Like shown in here [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Comment: `$this->get()` is just an alias for `$this->container->get()`. i fixed the `translator->translate` to `trans` sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the message directly in your controller.

Something like:

```
$t = $this->get('translator');
// ...
$builder->add ( 'firstName', 'text', array (
            'label' => 'register.first_name'
            'attr' => array (
                    'minlength' => "5",
                    'data-validation-minlength-message' => $t->trans('register.min_length');
            ) 
    ) );
```